# How can i do multiple conditionals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a question using rails

How can i do this code using rails

```
 select * from policy_vehicles where policy_id
    IN ( SELECT id FROM policies WHERE
    client_id IN (SELECT id FROM clients raz_soc = ?) )
```

Thanks i will appreciate help

Comment: This is atypical SQL, compared to what is normally found in Rails. It's doable, but it won't look like ordinary Ruby code. You're probably better off embedding it straight away: `PolicyVehicle.find_by_sql("YOUR QUERY HERE")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.map(&:id)Use the ActiveRecord where method. You can just pass in an array of values for your SQL IN clause.

```
PolicyVehicles.where(:column_a => value_a, :column_b => value_b)
```

So

```
PolicyVehicles.where(:client_id => Client.where(:column => :value).map(&:id) )
```